# 6125XLG blade switch IRF configuration in c7000 chassis

Tags: switch, network, hp

I have HPE c7000 chassis with 612XLG switches. I am trying to setup `IRF` between blades switches. somehow i am not able to bring up irf-port interface.

In 6125XGL TE1/0/17-20 ports are internal backplane ports connect two switch together. Let me know if i am wrong here.

Full config:

HP6125-A: https://pastebin.com/PXZYSext

HP6125-B: https://pastebin.com/QDudJGck

HP6125-A

```
<HP6125-A>display version
HP Comware Software, Version 7.1.045, Release 2406P01
Copyright (c) 2010-2014 Hewlett-Packard Development Company, L.P.
HP 6125XLG Blade Switch uptime is 0 weeks, 4 days, 22 hours, 2 minutes
Last reboot reason : User reboot

Boot image: flash:/6125xlg-cmw710-boot-r2406p01.bin
Boot image version: 7.1.045P14, Release 2406P01
  Compiled Sep 12 2014 20:49:24
System image: flash:/6125xlg-cmw710-system-r2406p01.bin
System image version: 7.1.045, Release 2406P01
  Compiled Sep 12 2014 20:49:45

    <HP6125-A>display irf
    MemberID    Role    Priority  CPU-Mac         Description
     *+1        Master  32        7848-5962-bf12  ---
    --------------------------------------------------
     * indicates the device is the master.
     + indicates the device through which the user logs in.
    
    <HP6125-A>dis irf conf
     MemberID NewID    IRF-Port1                     IRF-Port2
     1        1        Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/17     disable
                       Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/18
                       Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/19
                       Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/20
    
    <HP6125-A>dis irf lin
    Member 1
     IRF Port  Interface                             Status
     1         Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/17             UP
               Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/18             UP
               Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/19             UP
               Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/20             UP
     2         disable                               --
    
    
    <HP6125-A>dis irf top
                                  Topology Info
     -------------------------------------------------------------------------
                   IRF-Port1                IRF-Port2
     MemberID    Link       neighbor      Link       neighbor    Belong To
     1           TIMEOUT    ---           DIS        ---         7848-5962-bf12
```

HP6125-B

```
<HP6125-B>display version
HPE Comware Software, Version 7.1.045, Release 2422P02
Copyright (c) 2010-2016 Hewlett Packard Enterprise Development LP
HPE 6125XLG Blade Switch uptime is 0 weeks, 0 days, 1 hour, 22 minutes
Last reboot reason : USER reboot

Boot image: flash:/6125xlg-cmw710-boot-r2422p02.bin
Boot image version: 7.1.045, Release 2422P02
  Compiled Aug 05 2016 16:00:00
System image: flash:/6125xlg-cmw710-system-r2422p02.bin
System image version: 7.1.045, Release 2422P02
  Compiled Aug 05 2016 16:00:00

    <HP6125-B>display irf
    MemberID    Role    Priority  CPU-Mac         Description
     *+2        Master  30        00e0-fc0f-8c03  ---
    --------------------------------------------------
     * indicates the device is the master.
     + indicates the device through which the user logs in.
    
    <HP6125-B>dis irf conf
     MemberID NewID    IRF-Port1                     IRF-Port2
     2        2        disable                       Ten-GigabitEthernet2/0/17
                                                     Ten-GigabitEthernet2/0/18
                                                     Ten-GigabitEthernet2/0/19
                                                     Ten-GigabitEthernet2/0/20
    
    
    <HP6125-B>dis irf lin
    Member 2
     IRF Port  Interface                             Status
     1         disable                               --
     2         Ten-GigabitEthernet2/0/17             UP
               Ten-GigabitEthernet2/0/18             UP
               Ten-GigabitEthernet2/0/19             UP
               Ten-GigabitEthernet2/0/20             UP
    
    
    <HP6125-B>dis irf top
                                  Topology Info
     -------------------------------------------------------------------------
                   IRF-Port1                IRF-Port2
     MemberID    Link       neighbor      Link       neighbor    Belong To
     2           DIS        ---           DOWN       ---         00e0-fc0f-8c03
```

What could be wrong here?

Comment: Include the configs of each.

Comment: I have added full config. This is new setup so most of options are default.

Comment: E1/0/17-20 all 4 interface used for IRF. Do i need more interface like physical interface cross-connected?

Comment: **Problem Solved** - Both switches was running different version of software as you can see in my post. I thought IRF do auto-update of software but in my case stanby switch was running higher version. After match software on both switches IRF link up and working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As I recall, having set this up between a pair of 5700's, there must be an "up" and "down" direction - a "ring". It doesn't like being setup as a "stack", but can work with some luck. I'm not sure how to handle this with multiple interface, as I used a single 40G interface on each switch:

```
#
 version 7.1.045, Release 2432P06-US
#
 irf mac-address persistent timer
 irf auto-update enable
 undo irf link-delay
 irf member 1 priority 1
 irf member 2 priority 2
 irf member 1 description iSCSI-5700-1
 irf member 2 description iSCSI-5700-2
 irf mode enhanced
#
irf-port 1/1
 port group interface FortyGigE1/0/42
#
irf-port 2/2
 port group interface FortyGigE2/0/42
#
interface FortyGigE1/0/42
#
interface FortyGigE2/0/42
#
```

Comment: I don't remember how I got them to agree the first time, but I do recall it taking some poking. This setup has survived many reboots/power cycles for years. (as far as I know it's still working - no one has been screaming about it.)

Comment: What do you mean by Ring? I have only two switches and they are connected back-to-back with internal c7000 chassis backplane. why do i need ring here?

Comment: Oh! wait. i can see two member configuration in your snippet `irf member 1 priority 1` and `irf member 2 priority 2` but in my case i have just single member itself. Do you think my config is wrong?

Comment: Why do you have two separate ` irf-port 1/1` and `irf-port 2/2` ?

Comment: Ring as in E1/1 to E2/2, E2/1 to E3/2, E3/1 to E1/2. I'm only working with two switches and need the other 40G port for something else. My config is from a running stack, so one view of both switches. I assume you've followed "The Process" [everything ComWare has a Process] https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=c03477686 (also "1" is the highest priority)

Comment: I have slid software version difference between both switch if you check. Does that matter?

Comment: It could, but there should be log message if that was an issue. Again, have you followed the full, annoying process, including the switch reboot(s)? I've run into so many lame issues with comware because a simple process requires a non-intuitive, drawn out procedure.

Comment: It was software firmware version mis-match issue. after upgrade it works!